# Carregar informações nos inputs do modal com base no id enviado pelo clique no link data-id

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Usando a documentação do bootstrap,
fiz uma mudança de `a href` para `button`

```
<button type="button" class="btn-a" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditaFoto" 
    data-whatever="<?php echo $row['idfoto']; ?>"  
    data-whateverdatavisita="<?php echo $row['datavisita']; ?>" 
    data-whateveridvisita="<?php $row['idvisita']; ?>" 
    data-whateverpercetandamento="<?php $row['percentandamento']; ?>"
    data-whatevercaminhofoto="<?php $row['caminhofoto']; ?>"
    data-whateverdescricaofoto="<?php $row['descricaofoto']; ?>"
    >
 <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
```

Quando clicar no botão ele carrega as informações e manda para o Modal.

No JS:

```
$('#EditaFoto').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
    var recipientdatavisita = button.data('whateverdatavisita')
    var recipientidvisita = button.data('whateveridvisita')
    var recipientpercetandamento = button.data('whateverpercetandamento')
    var recipientcaminhofoto = button.data('whatevercaminhofoto')
    var recipientdescricaofoto = button.data('whateverdescricaofoto')

    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('ID Foto ' + recipient)
    modal.find('#datavisita').val(recipientdatavisita)
    modal.find('#idvisita').val(recipientidvisita)
    modal.find('#percentandamento').val(recipientpercetandamento)
    modal.find('#caminhofoto').val(recipientcaminhofoto)
    modal.find('#descricaofoto').val(recipientdescricaofoto)

})
```

Só que no caso ele só está funcionando essas duas partes:

```
data-whatever="<?php echo $row['idfoto']; ?>"  
data-whateverdatavisita="<?php echo $row['datavisita']; ?>"
```

As demais não são carregadas.
No PHP está tudo certo e os dados estão chegando alimentar as variáveis.

Comment: primeiro que o link não tem uma id para ser referenciado.
Segundo que dentro de `$("EditaFoto")` você precisa iniciar com `#`, assim: `$("#EditaFoto")` caso contrário ele vai procurar por uma tag chamada "EditaFoto" (ou seja `<EditaFoto> </EditaFoto>`)

Comment: Então mais como posso passar essa id?
a id eu pego com `<?php print($row['idf']); ?>` Só que não sei como passar nesse quesito para o Modal e carregar os dados.

Comment: Aí você colocou somente o link que clica para abrir a modal, os dados são apresentados numa tabela? Veja se essa resposta não te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239981/

Comment: Fiz uma modificação aqui no código, porém não está carregando os dados todos.
Editei a pergunta.